# Population of a selection box base on the Other Selection Box

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

Good Day! I have a problem I am trying to populate a Selection box base on the selected data on the other selection box here is my code

.py

```
licensetype = fields.Many2one('hr.licensetype','License Type')
license = fields.Many2one('hr.license','License')

@api.one
@api.onchange('licensetype')
def getlicense(self):
    if len(self.licensetype) > 0:
        mdlLicense= self.env['hr.license'].search([('license_name', '=', int(self.licensetype[0]))])
        #raise Warning(mdlLicense.ids)
        self.license = mdlLicense.ids
```

but still it populate all license I want to populate the License based on the selected License type. This is in Odoo8

Comment: license_name is integer fileds?

Comment: What does it mean `if len(self.licensetype) > 0:`? Didn't you want to write just `if self.licensetype:` instead?

Comment: Please clear your search criteria first. is license_name is integer type.? also share on what search condition you want to search.? what is relation between hr.licensetype and hr.license ?

Comment: @forvas this is only to check if licensetype field has a value or a user selected a license type

license_name is an integer in which it has a many2one relation in hr.licensetype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Domains**

A domain is a list of criteria, each criteria being a triple (either a list or a tuple) of (field_name, operator, value).

Here,

- **field_name** : 
  It's string type and must be from the current model or any relational traversal field through the Many2one/One2many field using membership (.) dot operator.

  **- operator** : It's for comparing field's value with passed value.
  Valid operator list **(>, >=, <, <=, =, !=, =?, ilike, like =like, =ilike, not like, not ilike, childs_of, in, not in)**
- **value** : It's for comparing with field's value.

Multiple criteria can be joined with three logical operators.
Logical AND, logical OR, logical NOT.

Read more about [domain](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#domains)

You can easily achieve this by defining domain for that field, no need to write any extra code.

Just put domain in your xml code.

```
<field name="licensetype" />
<field name="license" domain="[('licensetype','=',licensetype)]" />
```

**Note** :

Remember there must be relation between **hr.license** and **hr.licensetype**. licensetype must be Many2one in **hr.license**.

It will give the same effect as you want.

Comment: @Empire Technologies Pvt Thanks for the Help :D, It works